# Indicating discrete AI movement direction

Tags: c#, enums

I'm writing a simple AI function that will return the direction to move (Up, Down, Left, Right, stay still), and my first instinct is to use a simple Enum:

```
public enum Direction
{
    None,
    Up,
    Down,
    Left,
    Right
}
```

But I would also like to have diagonal directions, which would mean doing an even more verbose enum:

```
public enum Direction
{
    None,
    Up,
    UpLeft,
    Left,
    DownLeft,
    Down,
    DownRight,
    Right,
    UpRight
}
```

My function would be something similar to:

```
public Direction Move()
{
    Direction moveDirection;

    // Calculate direction to move

    return moveDirection;
}
```

However, I feel like there has to be a more elegant way of doing this. I thought about doing a `[Flags] enum` each for vertical and horizontal movement (basically two `bool`s), but then I can't include the `None` case.

My question is this: is there a better (cleaner, more concise, easier to modify/maintain) way to indicate in what direction I would like an entity to move? Constraints are that it should be discrete (so no Velocity vector).

Comment: N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW

Comment: vertical = 1/0/-1, horizontal = 1/0/-1. It makes for a 1 or 2 lines to determine target cell.

Comment: With Flags you can have the none case, just define it as `= 0`, and the others with factors of 2. If you don't add any flags (with bitwise operations), it will be equals to None. In my opinion that would be the most elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with enumeration flags to have "None" and still have combination of flags. In fact, usually with flags you have to have None to indicate no flags.

For example,

```
    [Flags]
    enum Direction
    {
        None = 0x0,
        East = 0x1,
        North = 0x2,
        West = 0x4,
        South = 0x8
    }
```

But... You may want to just add the diaganol directions anyway.. it could make life easier for example...

```
    [Flags]
    enum Direction
    {
        None = 0x0,
        East = 0x1,
        North= 0x2,
        West = 0x4,
        South = 0x8,
        NorthEast = Direction.North | Direction.East,
        NorthWest = Direction.North | Direction.West,
        SouthEast = Direction.South | Direction.East,
        SouthWest = Direction.South | Direction.West
    }

    private bool TestDirection(Direction input, Direction test)
    {
        return ((input & test) == test);        
    }

    private void SomeFunction(Direction d)
    {
        if(TestDirection(d, Direction.North) && TestDirection(d, Direction.West)) // NW
            // do something;
        if(TestDirection(d, Direction.NorthWest)) // NW
            // do something;
    }
```

I'd say that the 2nd if case here is easier to type out. One thing about this way of doing it is that if you do

```
TestDirection(Direction.North, Direction.NorthWest)
```

It will return true... I'm not sure if you want that... but you might. It may be easiest to just do this:

```
    enum Direction
    {
        None ,
        East ,
        North,
        West ,
        South,
        NorthEast, 
        NorthWest,
        SouthEast, 
        SouthWest
    }

    private void SomeFunction(Direction d)
    {
        if(d == Direction.NorthWest)
                // do something
    }
```

You may find this easier than using flags at all. Overall.. I'd say use whichever you find most convenient depending on your application. Another valid point with flags is this:

```
Direction d = Direction.North | Direction.West | Direction.East | Direction.South;
```

This doesn't make much sense... So maybe you want to just use the option without flags.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I still haven't really fleshed out the AI function returning the direction, so I'll likely wait until that logic is worked out to see which approach best suits my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Um i'm not sure how you would do this but, I have seen people make a tracking red box icon around the persons face and i guess if you could center the red box in the camera, you could then have the camera itself move so its always center no matter where you are... But that's just a theory. That could be the algorithm you could use!

Comment: What? I don't see how this applies to my question.

Comment: instead of speaking to your camera, you could just have it follow your movemnts like the kinect, but if thats not what you want you could just do a case method in C# which then makes it so you can just say case "right" (then have the following command)

Comment: case "right"                                                                       ___________AI.Speak("moving camera right")                              ___________Camera.move.right                                                //I think thats what you meant

Comment: Nothing to do with Kinect. Or the camera. I'm just asking about how a single AI method communicates its movement decision to the actor, both merely code objects.